# How do i do this in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get this function id

```
function load_gig()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gigs ORDER BY id DESC");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

and then put it in here

```
function load_game_gig()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE id= ");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

and then show it on the view

Comment: Side note, you should look into using [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for your queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the functions you've described above are model functions:

```
function load_game_gig($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE id= '.$id.'");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->first_row('array');
        }
    }
```

And then in controller:

```
$data = $this->model->load_gig();


$this->model->load_game_gig($data['id']);
```

Comment: `result_array` doesn't just return one row.  It returns an array of *all* returned rows.

Comment: You're right.. I edited my post to return only the first row in array